# I remember a certain card game. What is its name?

Tags: identify-this-game

I once saw a video of a guy explaining how to play a card game. The game was quite like MtG, with a few differences.
The "lands" were attached to the creatures. You paid for a creature by attaching the required number of "lands" to it, and I *think* you didn't get the "lands" back until the creature died. Damage dealt removed a number of the top cards of the damaged player's deck equal to the damage dealt, and you won by decking out your opponent.
I recall the cards having maybe a black or red border, and some of the cards looked vaguely like Hearthstone's [bloated zombie](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/hearthstone_gamepedia/images/3/3b/Bloated_Zombie_full.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180420125655).
It might have been a TCG or a CCG, but I think it might have actually been an LCG.

Comment: Do you remember when you played the game since most of these games only last a few years with an active player base?